# Spark: Local file system as default filesystem for spark application

Tags: apache-spark

I wrote a spark application in which i want to save dataframe in local filesystem.Spark needs to write a file in local filesystem. Then I use java.io.FileReader and FileWriter to read the local file written by spark , do some modification and then write it back in again in local filesystem. So the filepath I need to use is constant . for ex: file:////name.txt , This will be used for both dataframa.save and java fileReader and fileWriter

i used api like this:

```
dataframe.save(/abc/name.txt)
```

But spark is saving this file into HDFS. Do we have any env variable which needs to be set to make spark save file into local fs??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try `dataframe.save("file:///<LOCAL_PATH>/name.txt)`

Comment: this might not be a complete solution . At some other place in my application i am using java FileWriter to read the file. Exception is coming at that place java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/<LOCAL_PATH>/name.txt

Comment: Are you reading the file? or writing the file? Please specify clearly and also post the complete code.

Comment: Ok. By use case as follows: Spark write a file in local filesystem. Then I use java.io.FileReader and FileWriter to read the file written by spark , do some modification and then write it back in local filesystem. So the name i use for file is constant . for ex: file:///<LOCAL_PATH>/name.txt , will be used for both dataframa.save and java fileReader and fileWriter.

Comment: @Alok You need to edit your question to clarify.  Putting the clarification in a comment on an answer will mean no one will ever see it.